# PHP Debugging using Visual Studio Code on Windows 10

Tags: php

I am having difficulty in setting up Debugger to work using Visual studio code in Windows 10
I followed steps mentioned here.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nicktrog/2016/02/11/configuring-visual-studio-code-for-php-development/

Validated the phpinfo() here: https://xdebug.org/wizard.php
when i click on Start Debug icon, it shows the stepover bar and nothing happens although i have breakpoints in the code.

Am i missing something...or is there a way to see what's going on.

test.php:

```
<?php
$var1 = "Hello";
function test1() {
   echo "Hi";
}
test1();

?>
```

settings.json:

```
"php.validate.executablePath":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IIS Express\\PHP\\v7.1.0\\php.exe",
"php.validate.enable": true,
"php.validate.run": "onType"
```

launch.json:

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
           "port": 9000
       },
```

php.info:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\PHP\v7.1.0\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.0-7.1-vc14-nts-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Should work better with

```
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```